# List directory name in dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, directory

Why will this not list the directory - "2023"?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
directory = "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\FL\\2023"

df["Directory"] = os.path.basename(directory)
df
```

Comment: `df["Directory"]` will be a series rather than a single value. So try: `df["Directory"] = [os.path.basename(directory)]`

Comment: Indeed. You were right ! Not sure how can I mark you comment as answer.

Comment: I posted an answer with some more elaboration of what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### To get the result you want

Here you want to create a new column in a DataFrame with no existing rows. You can do this by assigning a list to the new column:

```
df["Directory"] = [os.path.basename(directory)]
```

Result:

```
                    Directory
0  C:\Users\Downloads\FL\2023
```

#### What the original code did

Your original syntax (where you assign a single value) has the effect of *setting that value for every row in the dataframe*. In your example that does nothing, because there are no existing rows. However, contrast it with a situation where the dataframe already contains some rows:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3], columns=["foo"])
directory = "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\FL\\2023"

df["Directory"] = os.path.basename(directory)
print(df)
```

Here, the directory name would be propagated to each of the existing rows:

```
   foo                   Directory
0    1  C:\Users\Downloads\FL\2023
1    2  C:\Users\Downloads\FL\2023
2    3  C:\Users\Downloads\FL\2023
```